Force position of vertices in a commutative diagram using xymatrix
I have the following code:
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[\xymatrixcolsep{2pc}\xymatrix{\Gamma[\mathbb{A}_k^m]\ar[d] & \Gamma[\mathbb{A}_k^n]\ar[l]_{F^\ast}\ar[d]\\
\Gamma[Y]=\dfrac{\Gamma[\mathbb{A}_k^m]}{\mathcal{I}(Y)} & \dfrac{\Gamma[\mathbb{A}_k^n]}{\mathcal{I}(Z)}=\Gamma[Z]\ar[l]^{\phi^\ast}}\]

\[\xymatrixcolsep{2pc}\xymatrix{\Gamma[\mathbb{A}_k^m]\ar[d] & \Gamma[\mathbb{A}_k^n]\ar[l]_{F^\ast}\ar[d]\\
\dfrac{\Gamma[\mathbb{A}_k^m]}{\mathcal{I}(Y)} & \dfrac{\Gamma[\mathbb{A}_k^n]}{\mathcal{I}(Z)}\ar[l]^{\phi^\ast}}\]

\end{document}

which gives the two diagrams

Now, what I want is to have the bottom arrow \phi^\ast be as long as the top arrow F^\ast, so that will sort of force \Gamma[Y]= and =\Gamma[Z] out of the frame (so it looks more like the second diagram, with \Gamma[Y]= and =\Gamma[Z] included in their places). I do not have much familiarity with spacing commands in xymatrix, nor could I figure something from the documentation. How do I achieve this?

I'm not sure why you correctly type \mathbb{A}, but also \mathcal I. There's no reason for being inconsistent.

@egreg: I had macros for both of them in my original document, and I just sort of rushed the removing. It does look odd, I will fix it.

@egreg: Just curious. Is there some sort of problem with skipping braces like in \mathcal I or \frac25? I do it most of the time, and it works fine.

\frac25 and \mathcal I aren't “wrong”, but cryptic. For the second case, consider that an editor might decide to separate the two token with a (soft or hard) line break.

Maybe not the best solution and not applicable in every case, but you could put the stuff that should hang over when positioning the arrows in zero-sized boxes (note the use of {} for proper spacing around the equals signs):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
    \xymatrixcolsep{2pc}\xymatrix{
        \Gamma[\mathbb{A}_k^m] \ar[d] & 
        \Gamma[\mathbb{A}_k^n]\ar[l]_{F^\ast} \ar[d] \\
        \makebox[0pt][r]{$\Gamma[Y]={}$}
        \dfrac{\Gamma[\mathbb{A}_k^m]}{\mathcal{I}(Y)} & 
        \dfrac{\Gamma[\mathbb{A}_k^n]}{\mathcal{I}(Z)}
        \makebox[0pt][l]{${}=\Gamma[Z]$} \ar[l]^{\phi^\ast}
    }
\]

\[
    \xymatrixcolsep{2pc}\xymatrix{
        \Gamma[\mathbb{A}_k^m] \ar[d] & 
        \Gamma[\mathbb{A}_k^n] \ar[l]_{F^\ast} \ar[d] \\
        \dfrac{\Gamma[\mathbb{A}_k^m]}{\mathcal{I}(Y)} & 
        \dfrac{\Gamma[\mathbb{A}_k^n]}{\mathcal{I}(Z)} \ar[l]^{\phi^\ast}
    }
\]
\end{document}



Beat me by seconds!

@egreg Oh, so you really need some recovery time …
